# How do I change the Windows Live account that my OneNote Syncs with?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2010, windows-live

I am using OneNote 2010 and I want to change the account it syncs with but I can't find it anywhere.  Anyone know how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the `Open` or `New` tab in Backstage View, where it says Microsoft Skydrive with a list of available notebooks, there is a link next to it which says `(Not Joe Soap?)`. About a year ago when I changed accounts, I clicked there and it logged me out of Windows Live, so I could save my new account information with OneNote.

Clicking on the link now just refreshes the available notebooks on my current account, and doesn't log me out of it. However, that could just be our IT dept blocking me from having any sort of control over my machine at all, so it might still work for you.

Answer (score 3):

The answer from Cindy Jayakumar is correct, but for me it required an additional step.

When I clicked on "Not Joe Blogs" it just refreshed the list of notebooks / did nothing.

> I had to **delete cookies in *Internet Explorer*** to get myself signed out.

N.B. I would have left this as a comment rather than an answer, but I don't yet have the reputation required.

Comment: I had a variation on this issue. For me it said "Not ?" and was missing my account name, but clicking this link would do nothing and I could not add any notebooks from onedrive in the meantime.

I checked all my windows credentials and found nothing to remove for onenote, but deleting my IE cookies finally got rid of the "Not ?" prompt, logged me out of onenote 2010 and let me re-login and everything worked again.